# Compiling GData for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to compile a project that uses the GData objective-c framework. I've successfully compiled and run the project under the 'Debug' configuration, but when I try to compile using 'Release' and now 'Adhoc' I get the following errors. NOTE: I duplicated the debug configuration for adhoc and that doesn't seem to help.

> "_kGDataGoogleAnalyticsDefaultAccountFeed", referenced from:
>   _kGDataGoogleAnalyticsDefaultAccountFeed$non_lazy_ptr in TKGoogleAnayliticsAPI.o ".objc_class_name_GDataFeedAnalyticsAccount",
>   referenced from:
>   literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@GDataFeedAnalyticsAccount in
>   TKGoogleAnayliticsAPI.o ".objc_class_name_GDataFeedAnalyticsData",
>   referenced from:
>   literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@GDataFeedAnalyticsData in
>   TKGoogleAnayliticsAPI.o ".objc_class_name_GDataQueryAnalytics",
>   referenced from: literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@GDataQueryAnalytics
>   in TKGoogleAnayliticsAPI.o
>   ".objc_class_name_GDataServiceGoogleAnalytics", referenced from:
>   literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@GDataServiceGoogleAnalytics in
>   TKGoogleAnayliticsAPI.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld returned
>   1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you missed linking the GData library in your "Release" configuration. When you added it, did you by chance make sure you had "All Configurations" selected or just "Debug"?

Answer (score 0):

try adding security framework and clean build